# Part on furnace making scratching noise

Tags: hvac, furnace

This spinning part on my furnace (not sure what the part is called) is making this scratching noise. When one section of the part hits the area behind it, it makes that noise. Any idea how I can remedy this?

https://youtu.be/7gY7n1wBO78

Looks like it’s [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01BLT28AS) part: 318977-401 - Carrier OEM Replacement Furnace Inducer Motor Blower Wheel/Squirrel Cage

Comment: In my experience the bearings go bad on inducer motors, creating drag and noise and slowing them down. Eventually your sensors will start tripping due to inadequate vacuum. Fortunately they're not terribly expensive and a fairly easy DIY project to repair. 

I can't say whether the part you've linked is the correct solution, though.

Comment: How long has it been making this noise? Make sure the part isn't loose on the shaft.

Comment: @JACK About a month now.

Comment: @isherwood, would replacing the entire inducer motor be the potential solution?

Comment: I imagine so. I didn't realize you could just replace the part you linked. I've had furnaces with a different style inducer.

Comment: Try removing the part and see if it's warped.  Try the motor to see if the noise is still there without the part on.

Comment: Might have a bird stuck in there, however that might keep it from moving at all.

Comment: If it isn't just rubbing the green wire, I'd have a replacement (motor, not that part) on hand before I messed with a snap ring. 'This' might not be the best time to open cans of worms for something that's simply annoying, w/o being ready to swap the whole thing out. You can always return it. - If you think *that's* a noisy inducer, I'd have to ask you to get in line.